# Bootstrap Collapse bugs out in html page

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

im trying to create a FAQ dropdown menu with bootstrap collapse.

So i created the collapse:

```
<div class="container textcontainer accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Was frühstücken die Kleinen?
                    </button>
                </h5>
                <button id="12a" class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne"><img src="img/click-elements/Arrow_FAQ.svg"></button>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Zum Frühstück sollen die Kinder einen kleinen Imbiss (Butterbrot, Obst, Joghurt etc.) mitbringen.
                    Süßigkeiten (dazu zählt auch die Milchschnitte) sollen grundsätzlich nicht mitgegeben werden.
                    Ein solches „Frühstück“ packen wir den Kindern wieder in die Tasche.</div>
                <button id="12a" class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne"><img src="img/click-elements/Line_FAQ.svg"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        Was frühstücken die Kleinen?
                    </button>
                </h5>
                <button id="12a" class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo"><img src="img/click-elements/Arrow_FAQ.svg"></button>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                    Zum Frühstück sollen die Kinder einen kleinen Imbiss (Butterbrot, Obst, Joghurt etc.) mitbringen.
                    Süßigkeiten (dazu zählt auch die Milchschnitte) sollen grundsätzlich nicht mitgegeben werden.
                    Ein solches „Frühstück“ packen wir den Kindern wieder in die Tasche.</div>
                <button id="12a" class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo"><img src="img/click-elements/Line_FAQ.svg"></button>
            </div>
        </div> <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                    Was frühstücken die Kleinen?
                </button>
            </h5>
            <button id="12a" class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree"><img src="img/click-elements/Arrow_FAQ.svg"></button>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                Zum Frühstück sollen die Kinder einen kleinen Imbiss (Butterbrot, Obst, Joghurt etc.) mitbringen.
                Süßigkeiten (dazu zählt auch die Milchschnitte) sollen grundsätzlich nicht mitgegeben werden.
                Ein solches „Frühstück“ packen wir den Kindern wieder in die Tasche.</div>
            <button id="12a" class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree"><img src="img/click-elements/Line_FAQ.svg"></button>
        </div>
    </div> <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingFour">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                    Was frühstücken die Kleinen?
                </button>
            </h5>
            <button id="12a" class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour"><img src="img/click-elements/Arrow_FAQ.svg"></button>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFour" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                Zum Frühstück sollen die Kinder einen kleinen Imbiss (Butterbrot, Obst, Joghurt etc.) mitbringen.
                Süßigkeiten (dazu zählt auch die Milchschnitte) sollen grundsätzlich nicht mitgegeben werden.
                Ein solches „Frühstück“ packen wir den Kindern wieder in die Tasche.</div>
            <button id="12a" class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour"><img src="img/click-elements/Line_FAQ.svg"></button>
        </div>
    </div> <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingFive">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFive">
                    Was frühstücken die Kleinen?
                </button>
            </h5>
            <button id="12a" class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive"><img src="img/click-elements/Arrow_FAQ.svg"></button>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFive" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                Zum Frühstück sollen die Kinder einen kleinen Imbiss (Butterbrot, Obst, Joghurt etc.) mitbringen.
                Süßigkeiten (dazu zählt auch die Milchschnitte) sollen grundsätzlich nicht mitgegeben werden.
                Ein solches „Frühstück“ packen wir den Kindern wieder in die Tasche.</div>
            <button id="12a" class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive"><img src="img/click-elements/Line_FAQ.svg"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

seen in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/9x35ka1d/13/

As you can see so far its working!

Now once i include it into my main page tho, its not working at all.
Im also using the bootstrap navbar which uses collapse too, so i thought they might be conflicting but that doenst seem to be the case.

its a lot of code so i packed it into another jsfiddle right here: https://jsfiddle.net/a3k0juof/2/
you can find the collapse way down.

i used the browser tools to look for the problem and it seems the js doesnt even trigger, but i cant find the solution.

any help would be appreciated.

with kind regards
jchanni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load jquery before bootstrap.

So instead of:

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
```

Do:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tfz6m082/

Comment: hahaha, just found it out too, but thx for the answer you are right!